# Regular expression question

Tags: regex, eclipse

Please help me construct a regex to match:

```
some text(x, x, x, x)
```

where x can be any integer either positive or negative.

I need it to match *exactly* as it is shown above.  Each x can be a different positive or negative integer.

Comment: What do you have so far and what problem are you having with it?

Comment: yes, i need it to match integers (not really any numbers..sorry)

Comment: Do there have to be exactly 4 numbers or could there be fewer or more than 4? Do all four number have to have the same value x, or can they be different? Can there be spaces around the commas?

Comment: I am trying to use Eclipse' (java ide) built in regex matcher (for find/replace and such)

Comment: and yes, exactly 4 numbers and there can be spaces around the commas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
[^(]+\(\s*-?\d+(\s*,\s*-?\d){3}\s*\)
```

Answer (score 1):

that exactly would be /text((-?\d+,?){,3})/

or more generally /^\w+((-?\d+,?)+)/

Comment: matches text(12 48 38 58).  I suggest something like this: /^\w+\(-?\d+(,?\s*\d+){3}\)/